# Springboot OffsetDateTime in response entity is serialized as BigDecimal

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jackson, openapi

I have an instance that contains a property `time` of type `OffsetDateTime` which i'm expecting its serialized value to be written in string when returning the instance in a response entity object, but the value is being serialized as BigDecimal instance, i honestly don't know what caused this behavior because there has been no changes to the configuration beans nor in the application properties that could cause this.

I understand that this could be fixed by specifying a custom serializer for `OffsetDateTime` and specify the serializer to use in a property's json annotation for jackson, but i don't want to do that as it was working as expected before and specifying the annotation with the serialization type is not possible because the controller mappings and returned types are generated using `OpenAPI` generator.

The generated class is like this:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param id 
 * @param name 
 * @param episodes 
 * @param languages 
 * @param time 
 * @param imagePath Relative path to where the image is located
 */
data class SeriesListInner(

    @get:JsonProperty("id", required = true) val id: kotlin.Long,

    @get:JsonProperty("name", required = true) val name: kotlin.String,

    @get:JsonProperty("episodes", required = true) val episodes: kotlin.Int,

    @get:JsonProperty("languages", required = true) val languages: kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.String>,

    @get:JsonProperty("time", required = true) val time: java.time.OffsetDateTime,

    @get:JsonProperty("imagePath") val imagePath: kotlin.String? = null
) {

}
```

Expected response:

```
[ {
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Series #1",
  "episodes" : 2,
  "languages" : [ ],
  "time" : "2023-07-26T01:16:11.789747Z",
  "imagePath" : null
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "name" : "Series #2",
  "episodes" : 2,
  "languages" : [ ],
  "time" : "2023-07-26T01:16:11.789747Z",
  "imagePath" : null
} ]
```

Actual response:

```
[ {
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Series #1",
  "episodes" : 2,
  "languages" : [ ],
  "time" : 1.690334171789747E9,
  "imagePath" : null
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "name" : "Series #2",
  "episodes" : 2,
  "languages" : [ ],
  "time" : 1.690334171789747E9,
  "imagePath" : null
} ]
```

This is the only configuration class in case this is asked:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class WebConfiguration : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
    }
}
```

Application's property file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${PG_HOST:localhost/postgres}
    username: ${PG_USERNAME:postgres}
    password: ${PG_PASSWORD:postgres}
  jackson:
    serialization:
      write-dates-as-timestamps: false
      write-durations-as-timestamps: false
api:
  data:
    config:
      default:
        resultLimit: 10
  media:
    config:
      baseUrl: ${MEDIA_URL:http://localhost:8888/media}
```

Gradle's implementation block:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa") {
        exclude(group = "ch.qos.logback", module = "logback-classic")
    }
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
//    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")

    // OpenAPI
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0")
    implementation("org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:6.6.0")


    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    itestImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    itestImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter")
    itestImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql")
    itestImplementation("io.rest-assured:rest-assured:5.3.1")
    itestImplementation("org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.18.3")
    itestImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.18.3")
//    itestImplementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.8")
}
```

I've found that the reason this happens is because the jackson serialization features `WRITE_DATE_AS_TIMESTAMPS` and `WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS` are enabled in the default serializer provider, i've found this upon debugging the classes in springboot inside `InstantSerializerBase` and so i've tried specifying those features in the application properties to be disabled but continues to show the same result.

I really don't know what causes this, i've cleaned the build and re-cloned the repository to no avail, so i came here to ask before i consider asking in github.

Comment: Curious (and probably frustrating). Has this changed overnight? And does the new, unwanted behaviour happen for all responses now?

Comment: Also is it happening in all environments? (Local computer, test and production environments)? No new versions of libraries? No change in the installation?

Comment: @OleV.V. I only have local and integration tests, both on which have the same result.. i found this issue when running the tests again, and as mentioned there were no changes. I've tried changing versions on spring and other dependencies but i still get the same result.. i will just have to debug where do the serialization features get parsed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, although i don't understand exactly why it happens.. perhaps there's some configuration that is not being properly set but this is what i've found.

I was checking through each commit on the repository to see which change introduced this bug, and i've found that one of my configuration classes which has `EnableWebMvc` annotation is what was causing this.

Reading its documentation states the following

> Note: only one @Configuration class may have the @EnableWebMvc
> annotation to import the Spring Web MVC configuration. There can
> however be multiple @Configuration classes implementing
> WebMvcConfigurer in order to customize the provided configuration. If
> WebMvcConfigurer does not expose some more advanced setting that needs
> to be configured, consider removing the @EnableWebMvc annotation and
> extending directly from WebMvcConfigurationSupport or
> DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration

Perhaps there was some default web configurer bean that was using that annotation which probably sets the configurations from the application files and somehow it set the serializer feature for dates to always serialize as `BigDecimal`.

Since i only needed to remove the annotation keep the rest of the configuration the same, i didn't need to do any advance configuration and the class was only configuring CORS. So basically the web configuration class is now only implementing `WebMvcConfigurer` and not using `EnableWebMvc` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is that jackson does't supported by default java 8 date/time and you should add a Set of support modules for Java 8 by adding these dependencies to your springboot app.

```
<!--    Parameter names -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
</dependency>

        <!--    Java 8 Date/time    -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>

       <!-- Java 8 Datatypes    -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and then you can register the object mapper programmatically as follows :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper =
new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
        .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, 
false);
```

or via application.yaml :

```
spring:
   jackson:
    serialization:
      WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: false
```

Comment: I've tried what you mentioned but it didn't.. i've added the gradle's implementation block in the post.

Comment: Also i don't think that could be a cause because i've found that upon debugging the default serializer has those serialization features as enabled, which is causing valuse to be serialized as BigDecimal

Comment: I use `om.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS); `however it probably sets the same flag either way.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. [jackson-datatype-jdk8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8) is deprecated and become part of Jackson since v2.8.5. Similarly, [jackson-datatype-jsr310](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-jsr310/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JSR310Module.html#:~:text=Deprecated.,differences%20in%20the%20default%20configuration) is also deprecated. The only module you need is at the current date is `JavaTimeModule`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solve it adding this:

```
@Bean
public JacksonJsonProvider jacksonProvider() {
    return new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(jackson2Http());
}

Add these to build.gradle:

implementation "org.json:json:20230227"
implementation 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs:3.6.1'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.14.2'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-modules-java8:2.14.2'
implementation 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs:3.6.1'
```

Comment: Your suggestion did not work